# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2501,201) (2501,)

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror, array-broadcasting, operands

I am new to python so please be nice.

I am trying to compare two Numpy arrays with the `np.logical_or` function. When I run the below code an error appears on the
`Percentile = np.logical_or(data2 > Per1, data2 < Per2)` 
line stating

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2501,201) (2501,)

```
data = 1st Array

data2 = 2nd Array

Per1 = np.percentile(data, 10, axis=1)

Per2 = np.percentile(data, 90, axis=1)

Percentile = np.logical_or(data2 > Per1, data2 < Per2)

print(Percentile)
```

I have checked the shape of both arrays and they both appear to be of the same shape `(2501,201)` `(2501,201)`. Therefore I am struggling to understand why this error occurs, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a dimension (by using `[:, None]` to `Per1` and `Per2` to make them broadcastable to data.

```
Percentile = np.logical_or(data2 > Per1[:, None], data2 < Per2[:, None])
```

Comment: That sorted it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the shape of Per1 or Per2, you will see that its value is `(2501,)` (since you take percentile along axis 1), so the error is thrown by both of those expressions `data2 > Per1`, `data2 < Per2`, in order to make your code working you need to make both operands of a compatible shape using `reshape`, which will turn your row-vectors into column-vectors:

```
Per1 = np.percentile(data, 10, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
Per2 = np.percentile(data, 90, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
```